# Can the Improved Cleaving Finish feat be triggered again by the attack it grants?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, multiattack, melee-combat

The [Improved Cleaving Finish](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/improved-cleaving-finish-combat/) feat says:

> If you make a melee attack, and your target drops to 0 or fewer hit points as a result of your attack, you can make another melee attack using your highest base attack bonus against another opponent within reach.

The way I understand it, Cleaving Finish is a passive proc. So, if I make a melee attack, kill Goblin A, I may immediately attack Goblin B. If this attack kills Goblin B, may I attack Goblin C? (D, E, F ... )

(Note that Improved Cleaving Finish explicitly states that you can use Cleaving Finish *any number of times per round*.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct, yes, you can continue cleaving into additional targets so long as you keep dropping the ones before. The odds of getting even one extra attack from Cleaving Finish are pretty low—creatures have to be bunched up together, and by definition you can only Cleaving Finish once per target. Having that attack then kill the second target and (with Improved Cleaving Finish) take an attack against a third target is vastly less likely still.

Note that Cleaving Finish works the same way Cleave did in D&D 3.5e, and Improved Cleaving Finish is equivalent to Great Cleave. No one takes those feats in D&D 3.5e, because they are bad. Making them cost *yet another feat* does not make them better. I strongly recommend avoiding all of the Cleave feats. They simply aren’t good.

Comment: There are situations they're viable (I made a Cleave build on a Dwarf that was functional) but generally they're pretty bad. It will vary by GM/Adventure as well because it is better against numerous small enemies but is basically worthless against 1-4 stronger opponents.

Comment: @Ifusaso The situations in which they work, are exactly the situations that are rarely any significant threat to an adventuring party (or, they’re an overwhelming threat, and the party needs to run). The d20 System does not handle mismatched levels and/or numbers well _at all_.

Comment: I have different experience, but that is generally true.